# Sidekiq servers in different machines consuming from one Redis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, background-process, sidekiq

Right now I have a Rails application hosted in Heroku and I also have the Sidekiq workers managed from there.

I am thinking on having Rails in Heroku as a client to push jobs to the Redis queue, and then have N machines that have Sidekiq daemons that get jobs from that Redis queue where rails is pushing jobs.

My question is:

- Can I have several Sidekiq daemons that process jobs from that same queue? I can't find an example that specifies how to do so. I have seen [sidekiq pure ruby](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/examples/por.rb), but I fail to see how would I write the server so that it starts fetching jobs.
- (This is what actually concerns me the most) Once the job is done, how do I send the results back to Rails? I am thinking on POSTing the result via JSON. But I would appreciate any feedback on this too.
- Finally, if it is possible to have several Sidekiq servers, from where should I manage all the workers/jobs/ - Set up the UI in the Rails side would be enough?

Comment: Check this out, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213499/can-multiple-sidekiq-instances-process-the-same-queue